# SQL select from the column and show specific output based on values in the column

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where i need to show specific value in new column if I find any specific value( i.e Open, close,WIP then open) and if status =closed then show closed

Data :

```
ID  SUBID  Status 
1    5     new
1    6     close
1    7     wip
2    22    closed
```

output i want to get

```
ID  status
1    open
2    closed
```

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Comment: can ID have closed and another status same time ?

Answer (score 3):

You could think about this backwards, and use the else to catch all 'non-closed' rows.

```
select distinct
   id,
   case when status = 'closed' then 'closed' else 'open' end
from 
   yourTable
```

Comment: Add distinct to get his exact output

Comment: How so @vkp since we are only selecting those two columns?

Comment: @vkp No worries at all brother -- usually you catch my errors so i started back tracking lol

Answer (score 0):

Scsimon's answer is 100% the best way to handle this based on your sample data.

Just want to add that if an id can have records with 'closed' and other records too (open, new, wip, etc.), use `CASE WHEN EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     ID,
     CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM YourTable T2 
                       WHERE T.ID = T2.ID 
                       AND Status = 'closed')
          THEN 'closed'
          ELSE 'open'
     END as Status
FROM YourTable T
```